# Datepicker with smartface icon insert

Tags: smartface.io

How to assign a button with picture for a datepicker defined on smartface?
When an icon assigned on datepcker structure it adds "select date.." text instead of image as button.

Comment: Can you show some code?  How are you doing it right now?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a imageButton to call showDatePicker method with images.

For example;

```
function showDate(){
SMF.UI.showDatePicker({
        currentDate : (new Date()).toString(), // date is given with JS date object
        mask : "dd-MM-yyyy",
        minDate : new Date("13 October, 2013"),
        maxDate : new Date("13 October, 2020"),
        showWorkingDate : true,
        onSelect : function (e) {
            var sDate = new Date(e.date);
            alert("Selected date: " + sDate.toString());
        },
        onCancel : function (e) {
            alert("Picker cancelled!");
        }
    });
}



var imageButton1 = new SMF.UI.ImageButton({
    width : "9.38%",
    height : "10.38%",
    left : "5%",
    top : "84.62%",
    touchEnabled : false,
    imageFillType : SMF.UI.ImageFillType.autosize,
    defaultImage : "datePicker.png", //which is your date icon
    highLightedImage : "content1.png", //which is your date icon when highligted
    inactiveImage : "content2.png", //which is your inactive date icon
    text : "",
    onPressed : showDate,
});
```